# is it "weaken Wi-Fi signal" or "weaken the Wi-Fi signal"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Could you tell me if I need to use *the* before *Wi-Fi signal* in the sentence below?

> If you have a Wi-Fi router in the living room, but you'll want to connect to it from another room, then the thick wooden walls may weaken (**the**) Wi-FI signal.

Would you please explain the logic of using it or not using it?

Comment: s/b "but you want"

Comment: More nit-picking.  • Technically, {the thick wooden walls might weaken the Wi-Fi signal} regardless of {whether or not you want to connect to it from the pertinent room}.  “Thick wooden walls can weaken Wi-Fi signals.  If you have a Wi-Fi router in your living room, and want to connect to it from another room, it might not work properly.”  • I would say “may” if this happened only sometimes (in this house)… and “might” if it might happen and we do not know.  (Definitely “the”, because you are talking about a particular, mentioned signal.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think *signal* might be used as a mass noun by some communications technologists, but in normal English it is a singular count noun, and so needs an article in most circumstances.

Here it needs *the*.

Comment: I think you're right that this is why it's *needed*, but even if it were a mass noun, it would still be best to use "the" with it. "Wi-Fi" (or "radiation") can be that mass noun, and while "the walls may weaken Wi-Fi" might be grammatically correct, I think "the walls may weaken the Wi-Fi" fits the context better.

Comment: @DanGetz: I think you're right; but it's much easier to make the argument from syntax than from semantics ;-)